# Agregar referencia a ensablado 'WindowsBase,Version=4.0.0.0...'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net

Tengo un problema con una clase ya que no me deja compilar por que se debe agregar referencia a un ensamblado pero se supone que si esta agregado ya baje y subí la version del Framework pero me sigue marcando el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Haga clic derecho en el proyecto 
Seleccione “Agregar referencia” 
Seleccione la pestaña .NET a la izquierda y busque “WindowsBase” en la lista de ensamblajes 
Haga doble clic en “WindowsBase” y se agregará la referencia del ensamblaje.

Comment: Es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.